# Android jar dependency

Tags: android, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I have imported a jar file in "libs" folder of a android project. I added it in my Java Build path. I am trying to call a function of this Jar file from my implemented Android SimpleService Class. My android project compiles correctly but while I launch it on the emulator, I get NOClassDefFoundError (@runtime it is not able to get the class file).

I am adding additional info for your knowledge:

```
    JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26.
    Android Platform = 4.0.3, API level = 15.
    Android SDK tools revision = 18.
    Android SDK Platform-tools revision = 11.
    Jar manifest file (MANIFEST.MF) = Manifest-Version: 1.0
                                      Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
                                      Created-By: Apache Maven
                                      Built-By: kunjan
                                      Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_26
```

Comment: Well it doesn't belong in assets, for one - libs maybe. try a clean?

Comment: Does the jar work right with a regular java application? Do you get any errors when you compile the APK?

Comment: Yes it works well with regular java application. No, I didnt get any errors during compilation.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to check whether that jar file is present in *.apk file or not?

Answer (score 0):

What version of ADT are you using?  If you are using 17 or later you can put it in a /libs folder.

Comment: We used 18 and even kept in /libs folder but still getting the same error NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: @KunjanSheth Does the jar show up underneath a new folder called "Android Dependencies"?  Go into your build path, look in "Order and Export" - it's possible your problem is simply that you are missing a check box somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem, if you are using ADT 17 or later, make sure that **use the 'libs folder' as source folder** . That is how I solved.